# HTML5 Video Background and Safari Not Playing Nice

Tags: safari, wordpress-theming, html5-video, z-index

Running into an issue with safari. For some reason, the footer is disappearing under the video until you hover over where it should be. Once you do that it pops into place and works normally. In order to replicate it, have the footer out of view, and reload the page, or click into a backpage and click back to home.

Tested on multiple Macs (MacPro using 1080p monitor, Macbook Air, and Macbook Pro) using all browsers, and the video works fine in Opera, Chrome, Firefox, even IE (parallels) but not safari. Windows machines have no issues using all browsers Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE.

The video background is being built onto a WordPress site using underscores as the base for the theme that I'm building.

The below URL is whats giving me fits.

http://yokellocalhosting.com/freddy/

Here is how I have the background setup in the HTML:

```
<?php if(is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <div id="videoContainer">
        <video autoplay loop id="videoBackground" preload="auto">
            <source src="http://yokellocalhosting.com/freddy/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Fabulous_Freddys_Background_MP4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="http://yokellocalhosting.com/freddy/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Fabulous_Freddys_Background_OGG.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
            <source src="http://yokellocalhosting.com/freddy/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Fabulous_Freddys_Background_WEBM.webm" type="video/webm" />
        </video>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the associated CSS:

```
#videoContainer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#videoBackground{
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

I know I have the MIME types for the server setup correctly. Just can't figure out what the issue is and why its doing what its doing.

Comment: How did you fixed that?

Comment: I couldn't find a fix, I think its a bug in Apple's implementation of Webkit on safari 7.X. As a work around, I used browser detection to target safari and set a static image instead of the video.

Comment: I had the same problem myself a few weeks back. I did the same thing - sniffed the browser and disabled the unsupported features on clunky old Safari.

Comment: It's disappointing to see Apple mess up webkit. Its such a good rendering engine.